# How to stop executing a query if a variable found

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this recursive query

```
select col1,  @pv:=col2 as 'col2' from colonnes
join
(select @pv:='Newyork')tmp
where col1=@pv
```

I want to stop executing the query if a `col2='paris'`

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I dont think we can do such thing.

Comment: Does this query actually do anything? It doesn't look like valid SQL to me....

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, go to Home > Status > Server; you'll see the running MySQL processes, with a Kill link for each one.